# Whitespaces not present when rendering JSON errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have been doing this in my controllers

```
render json: {errors: @user.errors}, status: 422
```

And when I see at browser console when user has errors on saving I see something like:

```
{errors: {my_field: ["Anerrorhasocurred"]}}
```

Where should I fix this error?

## Update

I forgot to write `{errors: ...}`, so I passing hash to `render json:` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try full_messages - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages

```
render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: 422
```

Should return an array of validation errors

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure the string has whitespace prior to jsonification?

Try adding a line that drops `@user.errors.inspect` to the dev log along with `@user.errors.to_json`, then retry the error.